# Import Existing SQL Server to SailsJS and Waterline?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have a large SQL Server Database with 300-400 tables that I would like to do a POC to try SailsJS. Is there anything out there to import an existing SQL Server db to the Waterline models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is not a way to do this.

Comment: If you would like an additional resource, here is a chat room for sails.js, node.js, and waterline questions. https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails